# How should I write this query?

Tags: mysql

I want to show all rows except the last two id. I have tried:

```
SELECT f.* FROM Failed_Order_EmailIds f WHERE id NOT IN
 (SELECT id FROM Failed_Order_EmailIds ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2)
```

This is giving the following error:

```
This version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'
```

Comment: Please elaborate. In what way is it not working? What do you want it to do?

Comment: so you want all rows except the last two?

Comment: Go to your previously asked questions and Accept the best suited answer. There will be a `Tick` sign just bellow the Rating up and down arrows. You have to click that `Tick` to green.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM Failed_Order_EmailIds f 
  LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT id FROM Failed_Order_EmailIds ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2)
  AS last2
    ON last2.id = f.id
WHERE last2.id IS NULL
```

You could also use this:

```
SELECT f.* 
FROM Failed_Order_EmailIds f 
WHERE f.id <
        ( SELECT MIN(id)
          FROM 
            ( SELECT id FROM Failed_Order_EmailIds ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 2)
            AS last2
        )
```

Comment: Thanks mate. This also worked and is taking 700ms to execute:-  select f1.* from  Failed_Order_EmailIds  f1 where f1.email not in ((select * from (select email from  Failed_Order_EmailIds  order by id desc limit 2) as f2))

Comment: @hitech: WHich version is faster with your data?

Comment: second version.The join one is taking just double time